# Can I save and read the saved value within a @Transactional annotated method is SpringBoot?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

As per my understanding, changes made within a single transaction should be visible within that transaction although the tx is not committed.

But I'm having an issue when trying to read the values after saving within a @Transactional annotated method. When the saved rows are fetched the updated values are not present. Is this how it's supposed to happen or am I doing something wrong here? This is how my code looks like

**DetailService.java**

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class DetailService {

    @Autowired
    private DetailRepository detailRepository;
   
    @Transactional
    public void updateDetails(List<DetailDTO> details, String sequence){
        updateOne(details);
        List<DetailDTO> updatedDetails = detailRepository.findAllBySequence(sequence);
        updatedDetails.forEach(ud -> log.info(ud.getOne())); // this prints null although this should be updated from previous method
    }

    private void updateOne(List<DetailDTO> details){
        details.forEach(detail -> {
            Optional<DetailEntity> dOpt = detailRepository.findById(detail.getId());
            dOpt.ifPresent(d -> {
                d.setOne(detail.getOne());
                detailRepository.save(d); // this is not required as this should be save on tx commit but right now I have it on my code
            });
        });
    }

}
```

**DetailRepository.java**

```java
@Repository
public interface DetailRepository extends JpaRespository<DetailEntity, Long> {
    List<DetailEntity> findAllBySequence(@Param("sequence") String sequence);
}
```

**application.yml**

```yml
# Datasource Settings
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db.xxxxx.co:5432/DatabaseName
    username: USERNAME
    password: PASSWORD
    #maxActive: 5 (This can be removed I guess. It has no effect or is deprecated)

    # Connection Pool Settings
    hikari:
      pool-name: xxxxxx-hikari
      maximum-pool-size: 5
      connection-timeout: 30000
      idle-timeout: 600000
      max-lifetime: 1800000

  # JPA Settings
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        physical_naming_strategy: c.s.l.u.util.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl
        default_schema: "DEFAULT_SCHEMA"
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
        proc:
          param_null_passing: true
      org:
        hibernate:
          envers:
            default_schema: "AUDIT"
            store_data_at_delete: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

As I have mentioned in the code comments I'm getting null values when I try to read the data right after updating them. I'm using **Sprint Boot 2.2.6** with a **Postgres 10.12** database

Comment: Are you sure you are updating and selecting the same entity? you update the entities based on the ID and you try to select "updated" entities by the sequence. Are you sure they both are with the same sequence? Or perhaps you want to update the entities with the sequence value as well ? Log the DetailEntity that you fetched on the save and the one you are trying to show and compare.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, I'm sure that I'm updating and selecting the same entity. The sequence is actually a foreign key referencing a parent table. I'm using the ID to update since I need to update those records with separate data.

Comment: There is one weird thing I noticed, your repository method is returning `List<DetailEntity>` and in your method you are assigning that call to `List<DetailDTO>` maybe there is a problem in the conversion ?